# How to get the column name of the one which value is closest to 0?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the data frame **df1** and I want to set another column with the name of the column that its value is closer to 0:

**df1**

```r
x <- c(1, 3,2) 
y <- c(2, 1,4) 
df1 <- data. frame(x, y) 
df1
#  x  y
#1 1  2
#2 3  1
#3 2  4
```

**The desire output:**

```r
 #  x   y  closer
 #1 1   2     x
 #2 3   1     y
 #3 2   4     x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `max.col` we can get the index of value which is closest to 0

```
max.col(-abs(df))
#[1] 1 2 1
```

to get column names we can use this index to subset it from `names` of the dataframe

```
df$closest <- names(df)[max.col(-abs(df))]
df
#  x y closest
#1 1 4       x
#2 5 2       y
#3 3 6       x
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 5L, 3L), y = c(4L, 2L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
df$closest <- colnames(df)[apply(df, 1, which.min)]
```

using the following `df`:

```
structure(list(x = c(1L, 5L, 3L), y = c(4L, 2L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)) -> df
```